# Can not to use POST in CURL

Tags: bash, curl, post

I am trying to make a script to use POST instead of GET but I not success at it.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: application/json"
echo ""
login=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | awk '{split($0,array,"&")} END{print array[1]}' | awk '{split($0,array,"=")} END{print array[2]}'`
clave=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | awk '{split($0,array,"&")} END{print array[2]}' | awk '{split($0,array,"=")} END{print array[2]}'`
if curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "username="$login"&passcode="$clave"" -X POST http://x.x.x.x/abc -s | grep -q mnp;
then
    echo 1
else
    echo 3
fi
```

the script works but it still using GET.

[screenshot of HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybs0H.png)

Any ideas about the right format of the Curl command?

Regards

Comment: The screenshot just shows the result of your command, not what command actually gets executed after your script runs. At the very least, show the value of `QUERY_STRING` used by your script, and how you run the script.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json` seems to suggest you should be posting... JSON?

Comment: Hi Chepner, I execute the script in a browser like http://<IP_apacheServer>/cgi-bin/login.sh?login=<username>&clave=<password> 
where login.sh is the name of the script and **login and clave** are the variable